# Display manager unrecognised service, trying to disable "x server" to install nvidia driver, debian wheezy

Tags: debian, nvidia, display-manager

First time install of Debian wheezy.

My nvidia 580gtx GPU is crashing GNOME and the computer. To get it to boot I had to use `nouveau.modeset=0` in GRUB. Now that I'm in, I want to install the newest NVidia driver so I can boot normally, but when I try and install it, it tells me to disable "x server".

I've tried:

```
$ sudo service xdm stop
$ sudo service lightdm stop
$ sudo service gdm stop
```

but they all fail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The service is called `gdm3`, not just `gdm`. This works:

```
$ sudo service gdm3 stop
```